# Jquery prevent html list going over multiple lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to prevent my users on a cms from making their menu item go over multiple lines as it doesn't look to good and can cut off their content.  I so far have this.

```
    <div id="sitewrap">
        <div id="wrap">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
                <ul> 
                <li><a href="#">Sub contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Share</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Extra Info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Extra Info</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If the width of the nav goes onto a second line I want the menu to look like this.

```
    <div id="wrap">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">More</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Share</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Extra Info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Extra Info</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I am trying to achieve this with Jquery but am stuck. [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/dbEhv/3/) (the second list in the fiddle is how I would want it to look)
I can count the width of the list items. But I want to say if the width is > 300 add all li that come after li = 300 to a sub ul of more like I have shown above in how I want it to look like. Any help here would be appreciated.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     var listWidth = [];
    $('#wrap ul li').each(function() {
        listWidth.push($(this).width());
    });

    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < listWidth.length; i++) {
        total += parseInt(listWidth[i]);
    }
        if (total > 300) 
        {
        alert ('to big');    
        }

        else {
         alert ('nice');    
        }    
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: It may not right solution to use script consider situation javascript disabled browser .try using css solutions for menu

Comment: @Paniyar fair point, I am not sure how easily it could be achieved in css, and I am happy for the low % of non js users to get the experience that doesn't quite look as good.

Comment: I started using twitter bootstrap for my projects. It has an awesome set of nav/navbars/dropdowns/etc.. Check this page out

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this, [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kKF3W/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var listWidth = [];
        var total = 0;
         // new li to append
        var li = $('<li><a>more</a></li>')
         // new ul to be appended to ul
        var ul = $('<ul>')

        // variable to store index of element after which new li(more) will be added
        var $index = true;

        // variable to state that index vaiable is set, no more index need to be set 
        var $value_set = true;
        $('#wrap ul li').each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).width());
            if (total > 300){
                if($value_set){
                    $index = $(this).index() - 2;
                    $value_set = false; 
                }
            }

        });
        $( "#wrap ul li:gt("+$index +")").each(function() {
            ul.append(this);
        });

        if(ul.length){
             $('#wrap ul').append(li.append(ul));

         }

    });
```

Comment: great answer, comments make it easy to understand! One thing I didn't consider in my question was that some users will have other sub menu's under their main menu, which doesn't work with what you have done, I have tried to only target the top li but it doesn't seem to work, do you have any advice here? http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/kKF3W/1/

Comment: On further testing I found that the more link will get appended even if the length is less than 300 (eg if I remove every item in the list except home it still says more), I tried to put if(ul.length){$('#wrap > ul').append(li.append(ul));}  into the if (total > 300){ statement but this didn't resolve this issue, do you have any ideas?